# Why my package.json file shows react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz" instead of react-native version

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, expo

Why my package.json file shows

> react-native:
> "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz"

instead of a react-native version like

> react-native: 0.60.

Because of this I'm getting this error:

> Error: react-native is not installed. Please run `npm install` or
> `yarn` in your project directory. Couldn't start project. Please fix
> the errors and restart the project.

Actually I've bought a react-native app from Codecanyon but the developer is not helping me to configure the app. It's been 4 days I'm not able to build the app. It has a php backend that I've uploaded and is working fine, but building app is a nightmare for me. Can anyone help?

Thanks

edit1:
So after removing the node_modules and doing yarn install again the app is giving this error :
fontFamily "AntDesign" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.
- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.

Here is my package.json file

```
    {
      "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
        "expo": "^38.0.0",
        "expo-ads-admob": "~8.2.1",
        "expo-facebook": "~8.2.1",
        "expo-font": "~8.2.1",
        "firebase": "7.9.0",
        "moment": "^2.27.0",
        "native-base": "^2.13.12",
        "react": "16.11.0",
        "react-dom": "16.11.0",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
        "react-native-carousel": "^0.12.0",
        "react-native-device-detection": "^0.2.1",
        "react-native-form-validator": "^0.3.2",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
        "react-native-map-link": "^2.7.10",
        "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
        "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
        "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.1",
        "react-native-root-toast": "^3.2.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
        "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
        "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
        "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
        "react-native-super-grid": "^4.0.2",
        "react-native-timeago": "^0.5.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
        "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
        "react-native-webview": "^10.3.2",
        "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
        "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
        "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
        "babel-preset-expo": "^8.2.3"
      },
      "private": true
    }
```

App.js:

> import React from 'react';
>
> ```
> import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
> import * as Font from 'expo-font';
> import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
> import { Root } from "native-base";
> import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
> import AppPreLoader from "./application/components/AppPreLoader";
> import firebaseConfig from './application/utils/Firebase';
> import * as firebase from 'firebase';
> firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
>
> import GuestNavigation from './application/navigations/Guest';
> import LoggedNavigation from './application/navigations/Logged';
>
> console.disableYellowBox = true;
>
> function cacheImages(images) {
>   return images.map(image => {
>     if (typeof image === 'string') {
>       return Image.prefetch(image);
>     } else {
>       return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
>     }
>   });
> }
>
> export default class App extends React.Component {
>
>   constructor () {
>     super();
>     this.state = {
>       isLogged: false,
>       loaded: false,
>       isReady: false,
>     }
>   }
>
> async _loadAssetsAsync() {
>     const imageAssets = cacheImages([
>       require('./assets/images/header.jpg'),
>       require('./assets/images/logo.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/logo_dark.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/star.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/avatar.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/emptylist.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/avatar.jpg'),
>       require('./assets/images/nointernet.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/contact.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/address.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/audience.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/schedule.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/phone.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/website.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/bookmarked.png'),
>       require('./assets/images/checked.png'),
>     ]);
>
>     await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);
>   }
>
>   async componentDidMount () {
>
>       await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
>       Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf")
>     });
>
>
>
>     await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
>       if(user !== null) {
>         this.setState({
>           isLogged: true,
>           loaded: true
>         });
>       } else {
>         this.setState({
>           isLogged: false,
>           loaded: true
>         });
>       }
>     })
>
>   }
>
>   render() {
>
>         if (!this.state.isReady) {
>       return (
>         <AppLoading
>           startAsync={this._loadAssetsAsync}
>           onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
>           onError={console.warn}
>         />
>       );
>     }
>
>     const {isLogged, loaded, isReady} = this.state;
>
>     if ( ! loaded) {
>       return (
>         <AppPreLoader/>
>         );
>     }
>
>     if(isLogged && isReady) {
>       return (
>         <Root>
>         <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" translucent={true} backgroundColor={'transparent'} />
>         
>         <LoggedNavigation />
>         </Root>
>         );
>     } else {
>       return (
>         <Root>
>         <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" translucent={true} backgroundColor={'transparent'} />
>         <GuestNavigation />
>         </Root>
>         );
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

edit2:
Also while installing packages I'm getting these warnings:

warning expo > expo-constants > fbjs > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3. warning expo > fbemitter > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3. warning react-native > fbjs-scripts > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3. warning react-native

> metro-babel-register > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.  warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411) warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > @hapi/joi > @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > @hapi/joi > @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > @hapi/joi > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated  and is no longer supported or maintained warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated  and is no longer supported or maintained warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > metro-core > jest-haste-map > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will  break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2. warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > metro-core > jest-haste-map > micromatch
> snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated warning react-native
> @react-native-community/cli > metro-core > jest-haste-map > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated warning react-native-web > deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead. [2/4] Fetching packages... info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module. info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.     [3/4] Linking dependencies... warning "native-base > eslint-config-prettier@6.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=3.14.1". warning "native-base > @codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@>=0.63.0". warning " > react-native-carousel@0.12.0" has unmet peer dependency "create-react-class@>=15.6.2". warning " > react-native-maps@0.27.1" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0 || ^16.0". warning " > react-native-render-html@4.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@>=15.5.10".

Comment: Did you try to run npm install?

Comment: yes using yarn install. If you want  I can share the app file with you. It would be nice of you if you could help me with this.

Comment: I think you should update your question with exact error you get and more details about package.json

Comment: Since you bought the app from CodeCanyon, they are responsible to give you support. Otherwise you can opt for a refund I guess. Regarding the above error, it seems to be that app is using Expo. After you install the packages, did you see folders inside `node_modules` folder ? Did you see any errors while you run the install (probably pasting that log would be helpful I guess).

Comment: No, Codecanyon doesn't have a refund policy. Anyways the nnode_modules looks okay to me but I did get warnings while installing packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why you are seeing a GitHub URL instead of react-native version.**

Because you are using expo and expo is a library based on react-native you are not using react-native-cli

https://docs.expo.io/

**Unable to start the project**

Follow these steps to start the peoject.

1. Remove node_modules folder.
2. run "yarn install".
3. run "expo start".

For the font loading have a look at this.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/

Comment: Already did that, literally, I've tried this for more than 5 times now. This App is making me crazy. The App developer is telling me that I have some problem with my environment but thats impossible since I've created many react-native apps in the past.

Comment: Tried that one? https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/248

Comment: Yes, but no success.

Comment: Could you provide me a re-producible example?

Comment: If you want I can provide you the App.